Fast forward and rewind video on YouTube in background mode
Is it possible to fast forward and rewind videos on YouTube in the mobile app in the background, for example using a Bluetooth remote control?

Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags before posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].
